# Golang validator custom validation rules for enum

Tags: go

I am using https://github.com/go-playground/validator and I need to create custom validation rules for different enum values. Here are my structures - https://go.dev/play/p/UmR6YH6cvK9. As you can see I have 3 different user types Admin, Moderator and Content creator and I want to adjust different password rules for them. For example admins, password length should be at least 7 symbols while Moderators should be at least 5. Is it possible to do this via tags in go-playground/validator?

My service gets List Of user and need to do validation with different rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method to `UserType` that uses the `validator` package to validate the users.

```golang
type UserType int

const (
    Admin UserType = iota
    Moderator
    ContentCreator
)

func (u UserType) Validate() error {
    switch u {
    case Admin:
        // validate admin
    case Moderator:
        // validate moderator
    case ContentCreator:
        // validate content creator
    default:
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid user type")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Calling validate would look something like this

```golang
func main() {
    a := User{
        Type:         Admin,
        Name:         "admin",
        Password:     "pass",
        LastActivity: time.Time{},
    }

    err := a.Type.Validate()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("invalid user: %w", err)
    }
}
```